# unable to add roles in asp.net identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I was using the following code to add roles of the user.

```
    Roles.AddUserToRole(model.Email, "COMPANYVIP");
```

and then i got this error:

```
    The Role Manager feature has not been enabled
```

after some research i found out that we have to add the following connection string in web.config

```
    <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <roleManager enabled="true" />
      </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

adding this eliminated my first error but now i get this error:

```
    A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server
```

what should i do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your change in `web.config` and in `Startup.Auth` add the following reference to `ConfigureAuth`:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    // Add this reference to RoleManager (without changing any other items)
    // Make sure it is added below ApplicationDbContext.Create
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
}
```

Then in your Controller, make sure it includes this in the constructor:

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
    // Add this
    private ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager;

    // Add roleManager
    public YourController(ApplicationRoleManager roleManager)
    {
        // Add this
        RoleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public ApplicationRoleManager RoleManager {
        get {
            return _roleManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        }
        private set {
            _roleManager = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and also include this in the Controller's Dispose (if you have it):

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        // include this
        if (_roleManager != null)
        {
            _roleManager.Dispose();
            _roleManager = null;
        }
    }

    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

You may also need to add this code to `IdentityConfig` (in the App_Start folder if you're using the template):

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string> roleStore)
    : base(roleStore)
    { }

    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(
        IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options,
        IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationRoleManager(
            new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        return manager;
    }
}
```

You should now be able to use the RoleManager in the Controller.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but as i was performing as you said. there was no ApplicationRoleManger class in my library. i searched and got this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417024/no-applicationrolemanager-class-in-my-mvc-5-template) and then i added the class manually as suggested. and now i get another error like this **An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code* where did i do wrong?

Comment: @Yogesh Gautam I've updated the answer to include reference to the RoleManager definition

Comment: Again i get the "value cannot be null error" on implementing var manager = new ApplicationRoleManager(
                new RoleStore<IdentityRole> (context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));

Comment: The above problem is solved. my mistake was that i added applicationrolemanage in ConfigureAuth method before creating the context . so it was showing me null value .

Comment: But again my problem is still not solved while adding user to role it gets disposed and shows me this error "The Role Manager feature has not been enabled." .

Comment: @Yogesh Gautam - I've updated the Controller constructor with more information in the answer

Comment: again there was the same problem.."The Role Manager feature has not been enabled" . I am new in this field so i getting so much errors .

Comment: @Yogesh Gautam - this is getting a bit painful! Are you using a standard template Visual Studio MVC project with Individual User Accounts enabled?

Comment: thank you for your time. My situation is i am using default register page and default login and there is no problem with that all of these logins are for normal users. all of these codes are on Default AccountController. Now among these users the master user will choose few users and give them special prevelages of VIP. and i have problem while the master assigns "VIPROLE" for those users. And what i am doing is i am adding vip using their username [Roles.AddUserToRole();] on CompanyController. is there anything that i did wrong? or any other suggestions please..

Comment: OK - just checking a few things - have you actually created the role COMPANYVIP?

Comment: OK - make sure (in ConfigureAuth) that the app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create); is added BELOW the ApplicationDbContext.Create and you can use var roleresult = UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "COMPANYVIP"); to add the user to the role (eg when the user registers) - note, this uses UserManager not RoleManager - see if this works now heh :-)

Comment: thanks that works perfectly fine i.e on registering roles is added successfully :) ....but again i have to add roles later after registration process from another controller...

Comment: OK excellent _ the best advice I can now give is refer you to the excellent article by John Atten to develop your idea further http://johnatten.com/2014/06/22/asp-net-identity-2-0-customizing-users-and-roles/#Re-Implementing-RoleStore-and-ApplicationRoleManager